# Stretching out the axes while using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I don't know if this has been answered before, I personally couldn't find another similar question so please be kind and help me out!

I have a simple histogram that looks like this:

[image]

Obviously, the main issue is actually making any sense of the data from this plot. Ideally, I want to **stretch out** the x-axis to get a better idea of the data.

If it's more helpful, this is my code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# arrays contain some misc data, not important for the question
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []

plt.figure()
plt.hist(a, bins=20)
plt.hist(b, bins=20)
plt.hist(c, bins=20)
plt.hist(d, bins=20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.close()
```

Please ignore the obvious issue of specifying an alpha value for each array.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_multihist.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the size of the figure itself to stretch the width of the frame. Then set the range to only display the data limiting the amount of wasted space.

Instead of:

```
plt.figure()
```

Use:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(width,height))
```

Also, you can set the range of the x-axis to limit the excess space. 'left' and 'right' representing the range you want to display within the graph.

```
plt.xlim(left, right)
```